# Minimum of moving windows based on hours in R

Tags: r, min

I have a dataframe, where the first column is the date, and the third the data. Like this:

[image]

I have to create moving windows, from 1:30:00 to 2:30:00 and 2:30:00-3:30:00 etc.
I have to search in the third column's every minimums, in all windows. I find this runmin() thing but it's not really works and don't understand how it works

Sample data:

```r
# build data programmatically
dat <- data.frame(
  timestamp = as.POSIXct("2020-01-19 01:30:00", tz = "UTC") + seq(0, 3600, by=600),
  int = 1L,
  val = c(25, 70, 68, 53, 63, 65, 52)
)
# dump of existing data, e.g., dput(head(dat, 6))
dat <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1579397400, 1579398000, 1579398600, 1579399200, 1579399800, 1579400400, 1579401000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), int = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), val = c(25, 70, 68, 53, 63, 65, 52)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: You say the first column is the date, but to me the first column here is `"2020:01:30`, which is most certainly (for most values) not a date. Can you provide the output from `dput(x)` is the top dozen or so lines of your data, with only the relevant columns?

Comment: I edited the original description!

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately you made it a little harder to do what is needed. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. (I'm suggesting an edit in 30sec that will provide two preferred methods for providing sample data.)

Comment: In general, you only need to provide one of the two methods I edited into your question, providing both as I have is unnecessary and/or maybe confusing. But either is *great* for making your question reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### base R

```r
bins <- seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-19 00:30:00", tz = "UTC"), length.out = 5, by = "hour")
bins
# [1] "2020-01-19 00:30:00 UTC" "2020-01-19 01:30:00 UTC" "2020-01-19 02:30:00 UTC"
# [4] "2020-01-19 03:30:00 UTC" "2020-01-19 04:30:00 UTC"
dat$bin <- bins[ findInterval(dat$timestamp, bins) ]
dat
#             timestamp int val                 bin
# 1 2020-01-19 01:30:00   1  25 2020-01-19 01:30:00
# 2 2020-01-19 01:40:00   1  70 2020-01-19 01:30:00
# 3 2020-01-19 01:50:00   1  68 2020-01-19 01:30:00
# 4 2020-01-19 02:00:00   1  53 2020-01-19 01:30:00
# 5 2020-01-19 02:10:00   1  63 2020-01-19 01:30:00
# 6 2020-01-19 02:20:00   1  65 2020-01-19 01:30:00
# 7 2020-01-19 02:30:00   1  52 2020-01-19 02:30:00
aggregate(val ~ bin, data = dat, FUN = min)
#                   bin val
# 1 2020-01-19 01:30:00  25
# 2 2020-01-19 02:30:00  52
```

If instead you need to add a column (preserving rows) that includes the min value for that group of times, then

```r
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$bin, function(z) transform(z, minval = min(val))))
#                                 timestamp int val                 bin minval
# 2020-01-19 01:30:00.1 2020-01-19 01:30:00   1  25 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2020-01-19 01:30:00.2 2020-01-19 01:40:00   1  70 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2020-01-19 01:30:00.3 2020-01-19 01:50:00   1  68 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2020-01-19 01:30:00.4 2020-01-19 02:00:00   1  53 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2020-01-19 01:30:00.5 2020-01-19 02:10:00   1  63 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2020-01-19 01:30:00.6 2020-01-19 02:20:00   1  65 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2020-01-19 02:30:00   2020-01-19 02:30:00   1  52 2020-01-19 02:30:00     52
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
# using `bins` from above
dat %>%
  mutate(bin = bins[ findInterval(timestamp, bins) ]) %>%
  group_by(bin) %>%
  summarize(val = min(val), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   bin                   val
#   <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 2020-01-19 01:30:00    25
# 2 2020-01-19 02:30:00    52
```

or

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(bin = bins[ findInterval(timestamp, bins) ]) %>%
  group_by(bin) %>%
  mutate(minval = min(val)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 7 x 5
#   timestamp             int   val bin                 minval
#   <dttm>              <int> <dbl> <dttm>               <dbl>
# 1 2020-01-19 01:30:00     1    25 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2 2020-01-19 01:40:00     1    70 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 3 2020-01-19 01:50:00     1    68 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 4 2020-01-19 02:00:00     1    53 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 5 2020-01-19 02:10:00     1    63 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 6 2020-01-19 02:20:00     1    65 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 7 2020-01-19 02:30:00     1    52 2020-01-19 02:30:00     52
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
# using
datDT[, bin := bins[ findInterval(timestamp, bins) ] ][, .(val = min(val)), by = .(bin) ]
#                    bin   val
#                 <POSc> <num>
# 1: 2020-01-19 01:30:00    25
# 2: 2020-01-19 02:30:00    52
```

or

```r
datDT[, bin := bins[ findInterval(timestamp, bins) ] ][, minval := min(val), by = .(bin) ]
datDT
#              timestamp   int   val                 bin minval
#                 <POSc> <int> <num>              <POSc>  <num>
# 1: 2020-01-19 01:30:00     1    25 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 2: 2020-01-19 01:40:00     1    70 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 3: 2020-01-19 01:50:00     1    68 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 4: 2020-01-19 02:00:00     1    53 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 5: 2020-01-19 02:10:00     1    63 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 6: 2020-01-19 02:20:00     1    65 2020-01-19 01:30:00     25
# 7: 2020-01-19 02:30:00     1    52 2020-01-19 02:30:00     52
```